# C++ SendInput not letting go off the key

Tags: c++, sendinput

I use these codes below, they keep holding both the left and right keys and never let go off them until I press those keys myself.

I could run the left key code and keep pressing the right key.. and it will keep pressing the left key.. only until I press the left key myself will it stop.

Same thing happens for the right key when I run the right key code it keeps pressing right I could press left key and it will still keep pressing right key until I press right key myself.

Reason why I used SendInput is because keybd_event is unreliable.. if you don't put a Sleep(Milliseconds) in between DOWN/UP it won't even do anything, and using a Sleep() will throw of the intent of this program it has to tap it as fast as possible, holding the key for any amount of time could result in the wrong answer (this is like a aiming program)

This one is for tapping the Right Key

```
INPUT ip[1];
ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[0].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[0].ki.time = 0;
ip[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip[0].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;

ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[1].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[1].ki.time = 0;
ip[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip[1].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

This one is for tapping the Left Key

```
INPUT ip[1];
ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[0].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[0].ki.time = 0;
ip[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip[0].ki.wVk = VK_LEFT; 
ip[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;

ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[1].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[1].ki.time = 0;
ip[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip[1].ki.wVk = VK_LEFT; 
ip[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Edit: New code looks like this, err don't like this style.

```
INPUT ip[1] = {0};
ip[0].type = ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[0].ki.wScan = ip[1].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[0].ki.time = ip[1].ki.time = 0;
ip[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = ip[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip[0].ki.wVk = ip[1].ki.wVk = VK_LEFT; 
ip[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
ip[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Edit again: (also doesn't work) I attempted to trick it into sending KEYUP first.

```
int intRetValue = -1;
INPUT ip[2] = {0};

ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[0].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[0].ki.time = 0;
ip[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
ip[0].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
ZeroMemory(&ip[1], sizeof(INPUT));
ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[1].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[1].ki.time = 0;
ip[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
ip[1].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip[1].ki.dwFlags = 0;
ZeroMemory(&ip[2], sizeof(INPUT));
ip[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[2].ki.wScan = 0;
ip[2].ki.time = 0;
ip[2].ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
ip[2].ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

intRetValue = SendInput(3, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
printf("retValue = %d\n", intRetValue);
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour when writing to `ip[1]`.

Comment: Side note: you can save coding space by making one and zeroing it, setting the type and VK code, sending it, setting the up flag, and sending that.

Comment: @chris I was thinking if I didn't send them as one package some delay/lag would occur and it wouldn't have the same effect.

Comment: @SSpoke, Yes, it depends on how robust you need it to be, but even then, zero them and just do, e.g., `ip[0].type = ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;`. Of course you still have to have an array that's big enough.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar How do I fix that? `INPUT ip = new INPUT[1];` or something?

Comment: @SSpoke : just enlarge your array to hold 2 items, not one.

Comment: Oh... I thought `[1]` meant 2 elements..

Comment: @chris: `SendInput` is an improved `keybd_event`, where the system will not interleave synthesized input with events generated from hardware. Suggesting to send single input events with `SendInput` to save coding space is ludicrous.

Comment: @IInspectable, I never mentioned `keybd_event`. All I was suggesting was cutting down on the repetitive code in the question. Using the first piece of code as an example, it becomes [this](http://pastebin.com/YF8BLTxu). Notice how half of the lines are no longer `<something> = 0;` and how the same data is no longer being repeated (DRY).

Comment: @chris: In your first comment you recommend to populate one `INPUT` structure, send it, then populate the next, send it, and so on. This is what `keybd_event` does. That's what I objected against. And it's also very different from your previous comment, which proposes the standard use case of `SendInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Can't use SendInput chained and without delays.

Need `Sleep(Milliseconds);` in between each other.

```
INPUT ip = {0};
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
ip.ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

Sleep(50); //Figure out the proper timing here

INPUT ip2 = {0};
ip2.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip2.ki.wScan = 0;
ip2.ki.time = 0;
ip2.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
ip2.ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT; 
ip2.ki.dwFlags = 2;
SendInput(1, &ip2, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: Do what? I have to use Sleep there?